# Vista Business doesn't cache domain credentials

Tags: windows-vista, active-directory, login

I'm using Vista Business (SP1) as a client and a Samba Server (Debian) as a domain controller. I can login without troubles into the domain when I'm connected to the LAN, but when I'm offline, I get the error message

> There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.

and cannot login.

Other users on the same network/domain controller can login while offline with their respective laptops, so I guess the server is not the problem.

the "cached credentials" registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\CachedLogonsCount` was always set at the default `10`.

How can I get this to work, so that I can login while NOT being connected to the LAN?

Comment: You meant, the "cachedlogonscount" key was set to 10, correct?

Comment: Yes, fixed the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you check the Local Security Policy (secpol.msc), under Local Policies, Security Options, verify that the Interactive logon: Number of previous logons to cache (in case domain controller is not available) is set to 10 logons. This will ensure the right registry value is set (CachedLogonsCount, as mentioned in a comment).

Comment: Yes, I meant the CachedLogonsCount.